# Segment classification on a vector image?

Tags: image, svg, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

All the methods that I've come across for segmentation of an image and classification of it's components require raster images - are there ways to do this if I have a vector image?

For example: I know that cityscape classification is a common use case, such as in this picture
[image]

Is there a process I can use that takes a vector image in black and white, for example something like this (assume this is a vector image):

[image]

and allows segmentation of all possible shapes and then classification of those shapes, or do I need to rasterize the image first? It seems counter-intuitive since all that vector information is being lost and then to basically re-vectorize it.

Comment: You might want to post this question at ai.stackexchange.com or datascience.stackexchange.com for some other perspectives.